# Plaintext Syntax Highlighting and/or Custom Highlighting Syntax

Tags: text-editors, syntax-highlighting, sublime-text-3, plaintext

How can you add custom syntax highlighting for a plaintext file? (for any filetype, not just txt)

I leave this question open to any editor for those who know - I'm not picky.
If you want me to be specific, assume Sublime Text 2 or 3.
(I write a lot of things in Sublime Text, I use many IDEs regularly, I used to use Notepad++.)

Sometimes I want to be able to write up notes in a file, but it would be helpful to have my own custom syntax highlighting for plaintext notes.

Is there a way to do this?

I would also consider an alternative file extension as a valid answer 
(like .yml)

What I'm looking for is a way to color "*", ">", "-", digits, etc. in a plaintext file (of any file type).

There are many ways to state this question, and I'm not finding anybody asking it.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I realize that a solution would be to have access to the Sublime Text files that define the syntax highlighting grammars. Does anyone know where those would be, so that I could examine them and make my own? (Your own grammar is not for the lay person, I know)

Comment: See [Notepad++ : Custom Syntax Highlighting for .txt files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877646/notepad-custom-syntax-highlighting-for-txt-files), [Notepad++ Custom Language Highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677962/notepad-custom-language-highlighting) ...

Comment: That's easy copy paste, and I found those. They're saying "no-NP++ can't" in the answers, which as a dev, I am aware of. Sublime has some ability to configure it's large language support. I'm essentially wondering if I can access the files that define the grammar for each syntax and make my own.

Comment: The accepted answer in the second link leads [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130518084439/http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Languages), which shows you how to set up a custom syntax highlighting scheme. Also the *Language* menu allows you to create a user-defined language and apply its highlighting rules to any file including text files. So how is that equivalent to "no NP++ can't"?

Comment: See top answer in the first link. Why is there no currently existing (non-archived) copy of that document if the process is still supported in Notepad++? Or is it no longer supported? (I'm going to have to look this up further when I have time) I'm looking to add a grammar to a set, not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Wiki page may have been deleted for a variety of reasons, or moved elsewhere. Doesn't mean feature's gone. `NP++ > Language menu > Define your language` shows [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/k6rjv.png).

Comment: Excellent. I should re-install it and take a look.

Comment: Maybe you should remove the NP++ tag and focus this question on Sublime Text. Perhaps add an NP++-specific question separately.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks for the help. I'm new being active on SU - and every SE has a different mindset.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the answer to my question:

http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/syntaxdefs.html?highlight=syntax

However, it's not completely transparent how you would add a new one.

A good answer is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646926/sublime-text-how-to-customize-syntax-highlighting

The answer is .tmTheme files as per this topic.